# how to get the content of JSON and put it in each html tags

Tags: json

newbie here, needs your help.

the content right now is static, so i want them to be dynamic, i want the to get the content from JSON script below and put on each heading and div.

here is my JSON xml content.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
   var info = {
       "items": {
           "phone" : [ {
               "product" : "iPhone 8",
               "manufacturer" : "Apple",
               "releaseDate" : "2018",
               "price" : 35000
               }, {
               "product" : "Galaxy S9",
               "manufacturer" : "Samsung",
               "releaseDate" : "2018",
               "price" : 33000
               }, {
               "product" : "Xperia ZZ",
               "manufacturer" : "Sony",
               "releaseDate" : "2020",
               "price" : 35000
               } ],
            "laptop" : [ {
               "product" : "MacBook PRO 2018",
               "manufacturer" : "Apple",
               "releaseDate" : "2017",
               "price" : 75000
               }, {
               "product" : "Vaio",
               "manufacturer" : "Sony",
               "releaseDate" : "2020",
               "price" : 73000
               } ]
       }
   };


   // render the items in the info using jQuery
   $(document).ready(function() {



   });

   // render the items in the info using native Javascript
   function load() {

   }
</script>
```

here is my div content as a static:

```
<h2>phones</h2>
            <div>
                <h3>iPhone 8</h3>
                <p>Manufactured by Apple, to be released in 2018</p>
                <form name="" method="post" action="">
                    <button type="submit">$35000</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h3>Galaxy S9</h3>
                <p>Manufactured by Samsung, to be released in 2018</p>
                <form name="" method="post" action="">
                    <button type="submit">$33000</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h3>Xperia ZZ</h3>
                <p>Manufactured by Sony, to be released in 2020</p>
                <form name="" method="post" action="">
                    <button type="submit">$35000</button>
                </form>
            </div>

            <h2>laptop</h2>
            <div>
                <h3>MacBook PRO 2018</h3>
                <p>Manufactured by Apple, to be released in 2017</p>
                <form name="" method="post" action="">
                    <button type="submit">$75000</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h3>Vaio</h3>
                <p>Manufactured by Sony, to be released in 2020</p>
                <form name="" method="post" action="">
                    <button type="submit">$73000</button>
                </form>
            </div>


thanks!
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried already. And what exactly you need our help with, we are here to help you solve problems not typing your code.

Comment: for your question, iterate through the JSON. assign it to the html elements. want some code help then show us what have you tried.

Comment: honestly i already tried guys but im not excellent at it:
see this link: http://codepen.io/graydirt/pen/gBuLK

Answer (score 0):

Deserialize JSON and simply iterate with "for" loop. You should get something like this:

```
var deserializedInfo = JSON.parse(info);
for (var item in deserializedInfo.items) {
    for (var product in item) {
        var productHtml = "";
        productHtml    .= "<div>";
        productHtml    .=    "<h3>" + product['product'] + "</h3>";
        productHtml    .=    "<p>" + product['manufacturer'] + "</p>";
        productHtml    .=    "<p>" + product['releaseDate'] + "</p>";
        productHtml    .=    "<form name='' method='post' action=''>";
        productHtml    .=      "<button>" + product['price'] + "</button>";
        productHtml    .=    "</form>";
        productHtml    .= "</div>";
        return productHtml; //or do whatever you need
    }
}
```

Comment: honestly i already tried but im not excellent at it:
see this link: http://codepen.io/graydirt/pen/gBuLK

Comment: see: http://codepen.io/graydirt/pen/gBuLK

i put it inside document.ready but i got an error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token = 
Uncaught ReferenceError: load is not defined